# node.js / node_mysql - stale connections get "NO database selected" error

Tags: mysql, node.js

We have a *node.js* app that uses [node_msyql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/), a great little library for accessing MySQL databases.

Unfortunately, if our connection is not used for maybe 8-10 hours, the next time we try to run a query, we get a `"No database selected"` error back from the server. We need to add a `"USE db"` somewhere, but I can't figure out where.

Now, it makes sense to me that connections would go stale, and it seems as though node_mysql is refreshing those stale connections, but there doesn't seem to be a way to make sure that the right db is connected.  I was looking for a `.connected()` callback or event or something that would let me make sure the correct DB was alway `USE`'d, but no luck so far.

Any suggestions how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ys, client tries to reconnect. You can try to query 'use db' on reconnect using code like this:

```
client._connection.on('connect', function() { client.query('use db'); })
```

This is where reconnection happen in the node-mysql ('end' handler):
https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/blob/master/lib/mysql/client.js

```
var connection = self._connection = new Stream(),
    parser = self._parser = new Parser();

connection
  .on('error', function(err) {
    var connectionError = err.code && err.code.match(/ECONNREFUSED|ENOTFOUND/);
    if (connectionError) {
      if (cb) {
        cb(err);
        return;
      }
    }

    self.emit('error', err);
  })
  .on('data', function(b) {
    parser.write(b);
  })
  .on('end', function() {
    if (self.ending) {
      self.connected = false;
      self.ending = false;
      return;
    }

    if (!self.connected) {
      return;
    }

    self.connected = false;
    self._prequeue(connect);
  });
connection.connect(self.port, self.host);
```

Comment: This answer works.  The other answer is to avoid the problem altogether and just set the database on the client object so that when it reconnects it does the `useDatabase` for you :P

Comment: change the driver :) Mysql auth handshake allows to include database. Some other drivers (including my - https://github.com/sidorares/nodejs-mysql-native ) use database if present during handshake. Currently my driver does not tries to reconnect lost connection, but I plan to implement it.

Comment: Also note that there is a problem with my solution: self._prequeue(connect); inserts auth command in the front of command queue and query('use db') will be added to the end of the queue. Other queued commends may fail.

Comment: 'Change the driver' advise was 'implement auth with db in node-mysql and send patch to @felixge', not 'use different driver'

Answer (score 0):

because of node-mysql update following code maybe work:

```
client._socket.on('connect', function() {
    console.log("use ",DB_NAME);
    client.query('use '+DB_NAME);
});
```

Comment: Because of node-mysql package update (currently 2.5), the correct event name is not "connect", but "connection"

Answer (score 0):

When using [the **node-mysql-promise** package](https://github.com/martinj/node-mysql-promise), you may want to use this code to do the same:

```
dbConn.pool.on('connection', function() {
    dbConn.pool.query("USE myDBname");
} );
```